# How to integrate Itô integral w.r.t time?

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

Let $W_t$ be a Brownian motion.
How to calculate the following integral
$$
I:=\int_0^t\left( \int_0^u(u-s)dW_s\right) du?
$$

My attempt so far is:
First note that
$$
\int_0 ^u (u-s)dW_s = \int_0^u udW_s - \int_0^u sdW_s =uW_u - \int_0^u sdW_s,
$$
so the integral $I$ becomes
\begin{equation}
    I= \int_0^t uW_u du - \int_0^t\left( \int_0^u sdW_s\right) du. \tag{1}
\end{equation}
Remembering that
$$
d(u^2W_u) = u^2dW_u + 2u W_u du, \quad \text{i.e.}\quad u W_u du = \frac{1}{2} d(u^2W_u)-\frac{1}{2}u^2dW_u,
$$
we can write the first term in equation (1) as
\begin{align*}
    \int_0^t uW_u du &= \int_0^t \frac{1}{2}d(u^2W_u) - \int_0^t \frac{1}{2}u^2 dW_u\\
    &=\frac{1}{2}t^2W_t - \int_0^t \frac{1}{2}u^2dW_u\\
    &= \int_0^t \frac{1}{2}(t^2-u^2)dW_u.
\end{align*}
Is this correct? And how should I calculate the latter term in equation (1), i.e. the integral
$$
\int_0^t\left( \int_0^u sdW_s\right) du?
$$

Comment: You only need to note that $\int_0^t\Big(\int_0^u(u-s)dW_s\Big) du = \int_0^t\Big(\int_s^t(u-s)du\Big) dW_s$.

Comment: This formula helps me a lot, thank you!
I thought of changing the order of integration; Fubini's theorem also works with Itô integrals? But I wasn't sure how to handle the limits of integration.